# Horizontal Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I am solving a problem where I am trying to create a horizontal tumblr theme with automatic paging. I am using pretty simple table for layout:

```
<table><tr>
    <!--each post is here--><td></td><!--To here-->
</tr></table>
```

But here is the problem. Javascript for automatic paging works really simple. You have to put posts into div, but you cannot put div into tr or table. If I put whole table in the div, horizontal layout naturally breaks. Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
<div class="repeating-div">    
    <table><tr>
        <!--each post is here--><td></td><!--To here-->
    </tr></table>
</div>
```

EDIT: It's external script not written by me, therefore it I have to put class on div instead of row and I really do not want to spend time writing new javascript code

Comment: what do you mean the horizontal layout breaks?

Comment: Do you really need a table for that?

Comment: I have a page that has to expand horizontally. YOu can do it either by using ul lists or tables. What I mean by "it breaks" is that repeating div puts two tables into code like this:
<div>
<table></table>
<table></table>
</div>
and they align vertically

Comment: You should use left floated divs inside a wrapper element to keep them all together, never ever use tables for layout.

Comment: OK... let's have a small html+css lesson... I float all the posts. What happens when they don't fit into the window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` to your DIVs. Using this property, multiple DIVs will tolerate each other, horizontally.

It's not recommended to use tables for non-tabulair data. If you want to add "table-behaviour" (appearance) to your elements, use `display:table` plus `display:table-row` and/or `display:table-cell`.

Comment: @Blackie123 `display:table-cell` will align the divs horizontally.

Comment: why didn't I think of that? Thank you! I really owe you this one!

Comment: Even using the display property to emulate a table is a really bad idea. There are many other, more proper, solutions. Unless the content is tabular data, you really shouldn't use either of those. Using display: inline-block with white-space: nowrap seems like the proper solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use inline divs and white-space: nowrap on wrapper div. The content floats to the right indefinetly and never breaks this way.

Comment: went with different approach, but it might have been awesome this way as well!

Comment: I was getting discouraged going through the other answers before I found this one. I was hoping I wasn't the only one who has done this before. This is the proper solution to this problem. Great post, Ladislav Bonita.

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:inline-block` on block elements won't work in IE 6-7. It will only work on inline elements.

If that's a concern, you could just float your divs to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Yea, I am aware of inline-block, but that breaks horizontal layout... Since it's inline element, it will break when it's too long to fit into windows, thus breaking layout!